# Не подключется javascript

Tags: javascript, pug

Не подключается javascript, вот как его подключил(в конце тега body)(использую pug)
    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js")
    sciprt(src="js/main.js") 
Вот что у меня в main.js

```
$(function(){
$(".buttonRadius").click(function(){
    $(".buttonRadius").hide();
});


});
```

Comment: С виду всё ок, в консоли что ?  Почему вы считаете, что JS не подключился ?

Answer (score 1):

ссылку на jquery в шапку нужно ставить

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"   integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

а поток где нужно код

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buttonRadius").click(function () {
    $(".buttonRadius").hide();
  });
});
```

**UPD**: Просто скопируйте код

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>
     <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"   integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <style type="text/css">
     .buttonRadius {
      background-color: red;
      color:white;
      padding:10px 20px;
     }
    
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <button class="buttonRadius">Lol4ik</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".buttonRadius").click(function () {
        $(".buttonRadius").hide();
      });
    });
    
    </script>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Нет, не работает

Comment: _ссылку на jquery в шапку нужно ставить_.  Не нужно. Как раз таки лучше перед </body>, чтобы скрипты не мешали загрузке страницы.

Comment: Так ладно щяс сам попробую - если получится :D ; UPD: у меня все работает. Я исправлю щяс ответ. просто код скопируй.